# htaccess rule to redirect to domain without hyphen not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains that point to the same directory on the apache server:

www.myexample.com and www.my-example.com

Now the domain with the hyphen should be redirected to the one without the hyphen.

I tried the following in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myexample.com [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work...?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is mod-rewrite loaded? Where are you putting the code? Do you have access to server config files?

Comment: Mod rewrite is loaded and works for several other Redirects. Just this one isn't working. And I don't have access to the server config files.

Comment: Is this .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Yes, htaccess is enabled. As I said, all other redirects work perfectly. It's just this one, that doesn't work.